# Ubuntu 20.04 does not boot. Syslog file is 223 giga

Tags: startup, syslog

I have a pc running Ubuntu 20.04.I found that my syslog file size is 223 giga and tried to restart my device and now it does not start at all.

Tried advanced settings and clean option but only removed 21 mega!

When I start, everything goes normally until a blank black screen is displayed and no more steps happens.

Please help. Thank you

Comment: Thank you for your response but I can start the device at all to delete the file !

Comment: Boot a LiveUSB. Use the "Try Ubuntu" environment. Mount your hard drive. Delete the syslog file. Reboot into your normal system. Soon after the successful reboot, review the newly-generated syslog to see why it's so enormous.

Comment: How to do this step "mount your hard drive"? I tried try Ubuntu but opened like a new device

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and directions. I hope you all the best man